# Altering all keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to rename/alter all the keys of a dict? As an example, let's look at the following dictionary:

```
a_dict = {'a_var1': 0.05,
          'a_var2': 4.0,
          'a_var3': 100.0,  
          'a_var4': 0.3}
```

I want to remove all the `a_` in the keys, so I end up with

```
a_dict = {'var1': 0.05,
          'var2': 4.0,
          'var3': 100.0,  
          'var4': 0.3}
```

Comment: Are all keys prefixed with `'a_'`, or can it be `'b_'`, `foo_'`, etc.? What to do in those cases?

Comment: Do you specifically want to alter keys in an existing dict, or would it be okay or maybe preferred to create a new dict?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is always the same prefix

Comment: @tobias_k I would prefer to alter them in an existing dict

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to alter the existing dict, instead of creating a new one, you can loop the keys, `pop` the old one, and insert the new, modified key with the old value.

```
>>> for k in list(a_dict):
...     a_dict[k[2:]] = a_dict.pop(k)     
...
>>> a_dict
{'var2': 4.0, 'var1': 0.05, 'var3': 100.0, 'var4': 0.3}
```

(Iterating a `list(a_dict)` will prevent errors due to concurrent modification.)

Strictly speaking, this, too, does not alter the existing keys, but inserts new keys, as it has to re-insert them according to their new hash codes. But it does alter the dictionary as a whole.

---

As noted in comments, updating the keys in the dict in a loop can in fact be slower than a dict comprehension. If this is a problem, you could also create a new dict using a dict comprehension, and then `clear` the existing dict and `update` it with the new values.

```
>>> b_dict = {k[2:]: a_dict[k] for k in a_dict}
>>> a_dict.clear()
>>> a_dict.update(b_dict)
```

Comment: Although this answers OP's question precisely, I would advise using a dict comprehension as presented in the other answers instead if the dict is or can be large, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
{k[2:]: v for k, v in a_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Technically, this does not alter any keys, but create a new dict.

Comment: ... as you _cannot_ change the keys of a dict

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I guess it's because OP is not familiar with terminology. Their intention is clear...

Comment: @tobias_k I agree, but this is indeed an unclear part in their question. "Altering all keys" is always impossible. You only know from their comment that they want to keep the original dict.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily enough with a dict comprehension.

```
a_dict = {'a_var1': 0.05,
          'a_var2': 4.0,
          'a_var3': 100.0,  
          'a_var4': 0.3}

a_dict = { k[2:]:v for k,v in a_dict.items() }
```

Result:

```
{'var1': 0.05, 'var2': 4.0, 'var3': 100.0, 'var4': 0.3}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function to replace key to match the desired format.

```
a_dict = {'a_var1': 0.05,
          'a_var2': 4.0,
          'a_var3': 100.0,  
          'a_var4': 0.3}

a_dict = {k.replace('a_', ''): v for k, v in a_dict.items()}
# {'var1': 0.05, 'var2': 4.0, 'var3': 100.0, 'var4': 0.3}
```